# dropdown list not getting populated in CI

Tags: php, html, codeigniter

I am designing application using CI. and want to show the drop down however its not displaying it.
 **View**

```
<label>Select Customer</label>
  <select name="name" id="name" class="form-control"  required="true">
 <option selected="">Select Customer</option>
  <?php if(isset($client_name)) {
  //var_dump($name);
 foreach($client_name as $tn)
  {
  $tn=(array)$tn;
  echo '<option selected="" value="'.$tn['name'].'" >'.$tn['name'].'</option>';
  //echo '<option selected="" value="'.$tn['tid'].'" >'.$tn['tname'].'</option>';
 }
 } 
else{
echo '<option selected="" value="Data Not found" >Error</option>';
}
?>
</select>
```

**Model:**

```
public function fetch_client(){
        $this->db->select('name');
        $this->db->distinct();
        $this->db->from($this->table);
        $query = $this->db->get();
        return $query->result();    
    }
```

**Controller**

```
<?php
defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Invoice extends CI_Controller {

    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        //$this->load->model('person_model','person');
        $this->load->model('client_model','client');    
    }

    public function index()
    {
        $this->load->helper('url');
        //$this->load->view('person_view');
        $data['client_name']=$this->client->fetch_client();
        $this->load->view('createinvoice',$data);
    }

    }
```

The front end is only displaying Error saying data not found. Not sure where I am going wrong. Please help !!!

Answer (score 0):

1.Check the query

```
var_dump($this->db->last_query());
```

2.Check the value in Controller

```
var_dump($data['client_name']);
```

3.Check the route is correct or not?

```
route["my-controller/my-method"] = "Invoice/index";
```

Answer (score 0):

Edit this

```
if(isset($client_name))
```

to

```
if(isset($client_name) && !empty($client_name))
```

then remove

```
selected=""
```

edit this

```
$this->db->distinct();
```

to

```
$this->db->distinct('id');
```

if you want use distinct.
you can change "id" to "name" if your table don't use id

Comment: Change $query->result() to $query->result_array(). If still error, could you pls var_dump your results

Answer (score 0):

```html
Try This Code :

Controller
<?php
defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Invoice extends CI_Controller {

    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        //$this->load->model('person_model','person');
        $this->load->model('client_model','client');    
    }

    public function index()
    {
        $this->load->helper('url');
        //$this->load->view('person_view');
        
        $fetch_record['client_name'] = $this->Model->select('city');
  $this->load->view('createinvoice',$fetch_record);
    }

    }


Model
 public function fetch_client($table){
        $this->db->distinct();
  $this->db->select('name'); 
  $this->db->from($table);  
  $r= $this->db->get($table);
  $res = $r->result();
  return $res; 
    } 


    

View
    <label>Select Customer</label>
  <select name="name" id="name" class="form-control"  required="true">
 <option selected="">Select Customer</option>
  <?php 
  if(!empty($client_name))  
  {
   //var_dump($name);
   foreach ($client_name as $c)
  {
   ?>
   <option value="<?php echo $c->name ?>"><?php echo $c->name; ?></option>
   <?php
   
  }
 } 
else
{
 echo '<option selected="" value="Data Not found" >Error</option>';
}
?>
</select>
```